# vb.net parsing aria-describedby in webbrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, wai-aria

I'm trying to get the inner text of a field I've not had to use before which is aria-describedby which is causing me a few issues.

Basically the way I used to get the name for the field before was simply

```
Document.GetElementById("id").InnerText
```

But using this method for aria-describedby doesn't seem to work and I cannot for the life of me figure out which other parameters to use.

On the web side of things all the tables within the webpage have the same structure the only thing that differs is the aria-describedb, see below

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;" title="some.user" aria-describedby="PackagesGrid_User">some.user</td>
```

The field I'm trying to return as text is aria-describedby="PackagesGrid_User" but I can't figure out how to pull that information, using the title isn't an option as the title always seems to be the result of the "PackagesGrid_User" which changes every time based on what is searched for.

In short I need to display the resulting name from the aria-describedby field using vb.net

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this in javascript?

Comment: The webpage is just basic HTML, the aria segment is just place in a table, the program is written in vb.net